# Thread won't stop when I want it to? (Java)

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a thread in my screen recording application that won't cooperate:

```
package recorder;

import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class RepeatThread extends Thread {
    volatile boolean stop;
    public volatile Thread recordingThread;
    JFrame frame;
    int count = 0;

    RepeatThread( JFrame myFrame ) {
        stop = false;
        frame = myFrame;
    }

    public void run() {
        while( stop == false ) {
            int loopDelay = 33; // 33 is approx. 1000/30, or 30 fps
            long loopStartTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            Insets insets = frame.getInsets(); // Get the shape we're recording

            try {
                ScreenRecorder.capture( frame.getX() + insets.left, 
                        frame.getY() + insets.top, frame.getWidth()
                        - ( insets.left + insets.right ), 
                        frame.getHeight() - ( insets.top + insets.bottom ) );
            }
            catch( AWTException e1 ) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch( IOException e1 ) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } // Add another picture

            long loopEndTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            int loopTime = (int )( loopEndTime - loopStartTime );
            if( loopTime < loopDelay ) {
                try {
                    sleep( loopDelay - loopTime ); // If we have extra time,
                                                   // sleep
                }
                catch( Exception e ) {
                } // If something interrupts it, I don't give a crap; just
                  // ignore it
            }
        }

    }

    public void endThread() {
        stop = true;
        count = 0;
        ScreenRecorder.reset();
        // Once I get this annoying thread to work, I have to make the pictures
        // into a video here!
    }
}
```

It's been bugging me for ages.  It periodically takes screenshots to the specified area.

When you start recording, it hides (decativates) the window.  On a Mac, when you give an application focus, any hidden windows will activate.  In my class `WListener` (which I have confirmed to work), I have:

```
    public void windowActivated(WindowEvent e) {
        if(ScreenRecorder.recordingThread != null) {
            ScreenRecorder.recordingThread.endThread();
        }
    }
```

So what SHOULD happen is, the screenshot-taking thread stops when he clicks on the application.  However, I must be brutally screwing something up, because when the thread is running, it won't even let the window reappear.  This is my first thread, so I expected a weird problem like this.  Do you know what's wrong?

EDIT: Okay, I made stop volatile, and here is the place where I make the thread:

```
package recorder;

import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.*;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class ScreenRecorder {

    static RepeatThread recordingThread;
    static int count;

    public static void record(JFrame frame) {

        if(recordingThread == null) { //Make a new thread if we don't have one
            recordingThread = new RepeatThread(frame);
            recordingThread.start();
        }
    }

    public static void capture(int x, int y, int width, int height) throws AWTException, IOException {
        // capture the whole screen
        //BufferedImage screencapture = new Robot().createScreenCapture(
        //      new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize()) );

        BufferedImage screencapture = new Robot().createScreenCapture(
                new Rectangle( x, y, width, height));

        // Save as JPEG
        File directory = new File("/Users/stuart/Movies/temp");
        if(directory.exists() == false) {
            directory.mkdirs();
        }

        count ++;
        File file = new File("/Users/stuart/Movies/temp/screencapture" + count + ".jpg");
        ImageIO.write(screencapture, "jpg", file);


        // Save as PNG
        // File file = new File("screencapture.png");
        // ImageIO.write(screencapture, "png", file);

    }

    public static void stop() {

    }

    public static void reset() {
        count = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: As per your rant on the code formatting: please read the right hand column for formatting rules while inside the message editor. Also take benefit of the *preview* which appears at the bottom of the edit page.

Comment: How do you create and start the thread?  Why does your thread have a reference to another thread inside of itself?

Comment: Your `windowActivated` method isn't thread safe, by the way. The state of `recordingThread` may change between the check and the operation if that particular method is called (*and affected*) by multiple threads.

Comment: Try declaring "stop" as volatile or using an AtomicBoolean.

Comment: I added the things requested.  And Donnie, I'm not even sure.  This is almost my first time dealing with threads, and I really can't get it to work.  I don't even know why I made a thread in a thread...  I really need help, because the tutorials only show how to make threads and use them for things that are so easy that it'd be faster if you didn't use one, but it doesn't help you beyond that.  They don't help you with difficult things that you use threads for.  I don't know where to turn for help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are clearly trying to execute a unit of work every X milliseconds, this will be far far easier if you use Java's Executors:

```
ScheduledExecutorService service = executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
service.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
    // do one iteration of your work
    ScreenRecorder.capture(...);
    ...
  }
}, 0L, 33L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

...
service.shutdown(); // to stop
```

Doing this manually with `Thread` isn't nearly as messy as you're making it (not a dig at you, just saying it's not that terrible in Java), but the above is still by far the simplest option.

Comment: It showing me the warning that static reference is accessed via instance variable, so shouldn't this be

ScheduledExecutorService service = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

Where the executer that you have defined is a global object i think?

Answer (score 1):

You need to make stop **volatile**, so that changes from another thread are picked up by your thread.

That will fix 1 bug, but there are some other thread related bugs. You should read Java Concurrency in Practice. You need to use **volatile** and **synchronized** when dealing with threads.